# How to make a bootable install DVD into multiple CD's

Tags: iso, optical-media

I have a bootable install DVD that I want to install on a older test server that only has a CD Rom.  How can I copy that DVD onto multiple CD's in order to install.

This server is a DL320 which has a combo CD/Floppy which is scsi.  I have tried to unplug it and plug in a IDE DVD rom with no luck.  Won't boot to the ide dvd rom.

Tried ubuntu live CD and tried mounting the ISO, but haven't been able to get that to work.

My options I can come up with.  Either purchase a new dvd/floppy combo, or get a way to burn that install dvd onto multiple CD's.  I am trying to do this with no additional cost as I have enough into my lab equipment already.

Notes:  DVD is an OS and application bootable DVD.  So the CD has to be bootable as well.  Also, I did create an ISO of it, so I can burn the CD from that.

So any advice on programs to do that?

Comment: What OS do you want to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used external USB DVD drives to install DVD media, but the better answer is to pick up (or make) a netboot CD that the server can read, and use it to install over the network.

Comment: I will try a network boot, should that not work, I will just replace the drive...  Thank you,

Answer (score 6):

It's not trivially possible to split an bootable DVD into multiple CDs, as the installation program(s) will expect all of the installation media to be coming from a single source. To support multiple sources the installation program would need modifying to know how the media is distributed across the CDs and prompt you to insert the correct one at each stage.

Comment: Yes, or it will give "could not find file" and you'd have to pop CDs in and out whenever it failed on something if it failed gracefully enough to allow you to "try again"

Comment: You would have to pre-empt how the installation app behaves at every hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

Applies To: Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2
If a .wim file is too large for your selected media, you can split the file into smaller files for spanning across multiple media. For example, if your .wim file is too large to fit on a single DVD, you can split the .wim file so that it spans several DVD-ROMs. To do this, use the Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) tool.
By default, the /Split-Image option creates new split .wim files, with a new .swm extension. The first file name is based on the specified file name, and each of the following files receives a number after it.
Example: Specifying the /SWMfile as "Install.wim" creates the new split files: "Install.swm", "Install2.swm", "Install3.swm", and so on.
ImportantImportant
In Windows 8.1 and Windows 8, Windows Setup does not support installing a split .wim file.
For earlier versions of Windows®, if you want to use Windows Setup to install a split .wim file by using the /installfrom command line parameter, you must name the split .wim file "install.swm", "install2.swm", and so on. Windows Setup specifically searches for split wim files named install*.swm. If you use a different file name, Windows Setup will not install the split Windows image.
To split an image

Determine the size of media required for the image.
Click Start, and type deployment. Right-click Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment and then select Run as administrator.
Split the image into a specific directory. For example, at the command prompt, type:
Dism /Split-Image /ImageFile:C:\data.wim /SWMFile:D:\imaging\install.swm /FileSize:600

where:
C:\data.wim is the name and the location of the image file that you want to split.

D:\imaging\install.swm is the destination name and the location for the split .wim files.

600 is the maximum size in MB for each of the split .wim files to be created.

In this example, the /split option creates an install.swm file, an install2.swm file, an install3.swm file, and so on, in the D:\Imaging directory.
noteNote
You cannot modify a split .wim file. You can apply the file to your destination computers only by using the /Apply-Image option in the DISM tool.
To create a spanned media on DVD

Determine how many .swm files were created, and create new folders for each file. For example, if two .swm files were created, you would create the following directories:
mkdir C:\span\DVD1\source 
mkdir C:\span\DVD2\source
Copy Install1.swm into c:\span\DVD1\source\ and Install2.swm into c:\span\dvd2\source.
Create an image (.iso) file for each subfolder, and burn each one to an individual DVD-ROM.
To make the first DVD-ROM bootable, use the Oscdimg tool and the appropriate boot sector file. For example, for x86-based computers running Windows 8.1 and using the Windows 8.1 version of the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (Windows ADK):
oscdimg -n -m –b"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\x86\Oscdimg\etfsboot.com" C:\span\DVD1\source C:\span\DVD1\DVD1.iso
Or, for x86-based computers running Windows 8 and using the Windows 8 version of the Windows ADK:
oscdimg -n -m –b"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\x86\Oscdimg\etfsboot.com" C:\span\DVD1\source C:\span\DVD1\DVD1.iso
For subsequent non-bootable images, you can omit the boot command-line option (-b). For example:
oscdimg -n C:\span\DVD2\source C:\span\DVD2\DVD2.iso
To build an AMD-EFI .iso file, use the following command:
oscdimg.exe -bC:\winpe-x64-efi\efisys.bin -pEF -u1 -udfver102 C:\winpe-x64-

Comment: While this answer is a giant pile of copy-pasted information, I appreciate that you at least tried to answer the question

Answer (score 1):

1.Load an older O/S disc like XP (SP2orSP3) that comes in CD form.

2.When you load XP, at the beginning it asks if you want to partition the disk.

3.1.Make a small partition say 10GB and a big one from the rest of the drive if you plan to use an external dvd drive or,

3.2.Make a big partition first (calculate to leave 10GB free) and a small one (those 10GB) if you plan to use a virtual a virtual drive tool.

4.In both cases choose to load XP to the small partition.

5.1.After XP has loaded run your installation dvd on an external dvd drive (corresponds to case 3.1. above) or,

5.2.Install the Power-ISO (or any other virtual drive) program to it and mount an ISO image of your installation dvd on its virtual drive (corresponds to case 3.2. above).

6. Choose to install it on the big partition.

NOTE: Some XP versions come with AHCI drive capability (newer or modified) and some with only IDE (original). Check with your BIOS what type is your drive and if you can change it down to IDE before you proceed. Also consider that some of the newer O/S s do not even recognize IDE type drives.

Answer (score 0):

What about using network booting? Relatively easy to setup. Google PXE booting

Answer (score 0):

If u r using linux then 2 choice one u can create a boot CD from your images/(folder) boot.iso u can boot from CD/Floppy and u can install from askmethod i e ftp/http/nfs.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to boot from the IDE DVDROM.  Double check your BIOS settings: reorder the boot sequence to put IDE ahead of everything else, ensure that the IDE controller is enabled, etc.  This is really the simplest way to go.

If you still have trouble, try flashing the BIOS to its latest revision (if it's older).

P.S. I just found a [little reference](http://forums13.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447627+1246030217707+28353475&threadId=1135393) to someone using the DL320 and is booting from the integrated IDE controller.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got iLO on the DL320? if so then you should be able to remotely mount the DVD image on the server.